# specify target dependency build order

Tags: iphone, xcode4

In my build phases, I have a few target that is specified there. Is there a way to specify the order in which the target is built? Or do I just order it sequentially top down and it will build it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode project knows about the dependancies between targets, and it'll automatically build the targets in the right order. You can tell Xcode about additional dependancies in the Target Dependancies section of the target info's Build Phases tab.